# Bash script to remove lines containing more than one word while maintaining any whitespaces (alginment)

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Example:

[tab][space]Stays

Stays2[space][tab]

this-line-will-also-stay

this line will not stay

I've tried using:
 `sed '/ /d'`

and:
`while read a b; do if [ -z "$b" ]`

However the white spaces get removed and no alignment is kept.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when you say alignment, do you mean indentation?

Comment: @Shloim yep that's what i mean :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to match a space that comes after a non-space:

```
sed '/[^ ] /d'
```

Or more robust:

```
sed '/[^[:space:]][[:space:]]/d'
```

Comment: `.` matches anything except new line, so it will match space characters too, if you meant to use non space use `\S`

Comment: I wanted: <line start><any character 0 or more times><non space character><space>

Comment: @CodeManiac In `sed`, `.` matches even a newline granted it is in the pattern space. `\S` is only supported in GNU `sed`

Comment: @Shloim I'm not sure this will work if there are spaces or tabs at the start of the line

Comment: This sed removes any line that contains spaces AFTER non spaces. so leading spaces will not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

perl to use more powerful regular expressions than sed gives you:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /^\s*\S+\s*$/' input.txt
     Stays
Stays2  
this-line-will-also-stay
```

Any line that starts with 0 or more leading whitespace characters, 1 or more non-whitespace characters, and 0 or more whitespace characters at the end will be printed. Anything else will be ignored.

---

You can do the same in sed but it's a bit more cumbersome due to basic regular expressions:

```
$ sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]*$/p' input.txt
     Stays
Stays2  
this-line-will-also-stay
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove all lines where there are at least 2 non-whitespace chars separated with 1+ whitespace chars:

```
sed '/[^[:space:]][[:space:]]\{1,\}[^[:space:]]/d' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/WolylG):

```
s="  Stays
Stays2  
this-line-will-also-stay
this line will not stay"

sed '/[^[:space:]][[:space:]]\{1,\}[^[:space:]]/d' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
     Stays
Stays2  
this-line-will-also-stay
```

Comment: Considering we took opposite approaches, it's funny how similar the two REs are.

Comment: @Shawn POSIX ERE can be used, too, then `+` can be used as a quantifier: `sed -E '/[^[:space:]][[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]/d' file"`

Comment: That's not standard or even all that portable -- IIRC, gnu sed uses `-r` for that purpose, and I'd be surprised if any of the commercial unixes like AIX supports either option. (Granted, OP did tag the question linux...)

Comment: @Shawn I know, I am working only in Linux, so I am accustomed to `-E` and GNU `sed`.